# Dictionaries: Integrating 2 values to one key using a list item which has been converted to a string

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I am trying to integrate a dictionary as a key of another dictionary. At the same time I am trying to extend a key('day') value pair of a python dictionary with a second value out of list (a) using the following code:

```
dictionary = [{'day': int(a[1]),
                      'year': (a[2])}]

big_dictionary['sub_dictionary'] = dictionary
            dictionary['day'].extend(int(a[6]))
```

I receive the following error message:'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str;'
Hence I attempted to convert the added value into string. Yet I am receiving the same TypeError.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: `dictionary` isn't a dictionary, its a list of dictionaries, `dicitonary[0]["day"]` is an integer, which you can't extend.

Comment: Thanks!So maybe convert to int after the extension?

Comment: Provide an example of how the output should look like.